# Number of occurrences of a number in a list

Tags: python

This program below is supposed to count the number of occurrences of x in a list. Can not identify the error in the code

```
def count_x( items, x ):
    if items==[]:
        return 0
    first = items.pop(0)
    if first == x:
        return 1 + count_x(items, x)
```

Comment: Post the stack trace

Comment: Calling the last item in the list `first` is an odd choice of variable names. In any event -- what does your code do if `first` *isn't* equal to `x`?

Comment: @JohnColeman `items.pop(0)` returns the first item in the list.

Comment: What if `first` *isn't* equal to `x`?  What does your function return in that case?

Comment: You do know you can do `val = items.count(x)`,don't you?

Comment: @TimRoberts You are right of course -- I didn't see that `0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are better ways to do this, but it's worth addressing why your code is throwing an error.

You don't have a case for when the item popped is not equal to your search item. This causes the function to return a None. Since it is working recursively, it tries to compute `int + None`, which leads to an error.

The other issue is that you are modifying the list with the function, which you may not want.  For example:

```
def count_x( items, x ):
    print(items)
    if items==[]:
        return 0
    first = items.pop(0)
    if first == x:
        return 1 + count_x(items, x)
    
    else:
        return count_x(items, x)

items = [1, 2, 1, 1]

print(count_x(items, 1))

print(items)
```

Your `items` will become an empty list after you run the function.

Comment: Don't just describe the problem, explain how to fix it and show the corrected code. You may think the readers should be able to figure it out from your description, but believe me, they can't.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should work as following:

```py
def count_x(items:list, x ):
    count = 0
    for item in items:
        if item == x:
            count = count + 1
    return count

count = count_x(items, x)
```

You could also simply use `count = items.count(x)` tho.

Comment: They're obviously using this as an exercise to learn recursion. Showing an iterative solution is not helpful.